# SQLAlchemy pre-filtered query with optional workaround

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy I've subclassed query in order to pre-filter my queries according to the pre-filter recipe: [Pre-Filtering Query](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery)

But in some cases I want to work around the pre-filter to include the results that were filtered out. An example in Flask-SQLAlchemy has a method in the query but I'm struggling to adapt it to my normal sqlachemy.

```
class QueryWithSoftDelete(BaseQuery):
   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       obj = super(QueryWithSoftDelete, cls).__new__(cls)
       with_deleted = kwargs.pop('_with_deleted', False)
       if len(args) > 0:
           super(QueryWithSoftDelete, obj).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           return obj.filter_by(deleted=False) if not with_deleted else obj
       return obj

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       pass

   def with_deleted(self):
       return self.__class__(db.class_mapper(self._mapper_zero().class_),
                             session=db.session(), _with_deleted=True)
```

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/implementing-the-soft-delete-pattern-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy

How can I include those results in my queries?